# Unable to invoke REST resource deployed on Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) remote server. When it work on localhost without any issue

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

I have written a dynamic web application using following tools:

- AngularJS - REST call
- JQuery - REST call to update pie chart
- JAX-RS
- Jersey
- Weblogic 12c (12.1.3)

These are jars in lib folder shown in this image:

[image: Jars in lib folder]

REST Resource

```
@Path("/audit")
public class AuditResource {

    private AuditLogService auditLogService = new AuditLogServiceImpl();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/all")
    public List<AuditLog> getAllLog() {
        List<AuditLog> allLog = null;
        try {

            allLog = auditLogService.getAllLog();

        } catch(final ApplicationException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        if(allLog != null && allLog.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Data not found", Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return allLog;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>my.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

AngularJS controller

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.allLog = function() {


        $http.get("services/audit/all")
        .then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.logs = response.data;

        },  function errorCallback(response) {

            console.log(response);
        });

    };

    $scope.allLog();
}]);
```

Executing this AngularJS controller and jQuery AJAX call definitely works on localhost without any problem, however it does not work when deployed on already running remote Weblogic server. Does anyone faced the same issue? And able to solve the riddle?

When I run the application on remote weblogic server following message prints on console

```
http://hostIP:7011/AuditLogView/services/audit/all

 Object {data: "Not Found", status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "Not Found"}
```

Another issue is the log4j is unable to write logs on remote server.

log4j configurations and lib shown in this image:

[image: log4j configuration]

When the application deploys on localhost in logs it shows a warning in eclipse console, although in lib directory **jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar** already exists. If it does not create issue on localhost then, I am less worried about it.

```
WARNING: 
**********
The application is using ServletContainerInitializer class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer that is loaded from:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/jersey-servlet-1.18.jar. This initializer overrides the one available in the system.
**********
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Weblogic will override embedded jars with its own, possibly using the wrong version.  It looks like this is what's happening with jersey.  You can a weblogic deployment descriptor called `/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` similar to the following:

```
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name><!-- put jersey package here, e.g. org.glassfish.jersey.* --></package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>

        <prefer-application-resources>
            <resource-name><!-- put jersey package here, e.g. org.glassfish.jersey.* --></resource-name>
        </prefer-application-resources>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root><!-- your app context --></context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

You may have to add multiple `<package-name>` and `<resource-name>` elements to get all your jars loaded correctly.  It's one of the pains of using weblogic.

It's probably a similar issue with log4j, bot the jar and your log4j.properties

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was under the weather. I have tried your suggestions but it is failing to invoke 'services/audit/all' relative URL (REST path). I tried with full URL as well including http:// protocol but did not help much.

Comment: I have mentioned log file in weblogic configurations. It is showing following text.  I am not using Spring framework.
<pre> 
####<Aug 22, 2016 5:42:56 PM IST> <Info> <ServletContext-/AuditLogView> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '40' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath> 
</pre>

Comment: That log entry is info level, I wouldn't worry about it.  What error(s) are you getting?